# Azure Alerts on bespoke endpoint status

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I have a platform which has a series of services which each have a health status.
If the status is "foobar" I'd like to be alerted.

Is there a way to call a service end point to return the status and then conditionally alert on this using Azure Monitoring and alerting functionality?

My fallback position is to make use of  metric alerts on logs.

Thanks!

Comment: Application insights SDK offers handling of bespoke events. This seems like something that could be used to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The best out-of-the-box approach would be to utilize Application Insight's Availability Tests (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability) for documentation).

Otherwise your idea of using log-based alerts is the only other option